# python error : too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, indices

My input was a csv file which was imported to postgresqldb .Later i am building a cnn using keras.My code below gives the following error "IndexError: too many indices for array". I am quite new to machine learning so I do not have any idea about how to solve this. Any suggestions?

```
X = dataframe1[['Feature1','Feature2','Feature3','Feature4','Feature5','Feature6','Feature7','Feature8','Feature9','Feature10','Feature11\1','Feature12','Feature13','Feature14']]
Y=result[['label']]



# evaluate model with standardized dataset
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-50-0e5d0345015f> in <module>()
          2 estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
          3 kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    ----> 4 results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
          5 print("Results: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))

    C:\Anacondav3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
        129 
        130     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    --> 131     cv_iter = list(cv.split(X, y, groups))
        132     scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
        133     # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are

    C:\Anacondav3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
        320                                                              n_samples))
        321 
    --> 322         for train, test in super(_BaseKFold, self).split(X, y, groups):
        323             yield train, test
        324 

    C:\Anacondav3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
         89         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
         90         indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
    ---> 91         for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
         92             train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
         93             test_index = indices[test_index]

    C:\Anacondav3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
        608 
        609     def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
    --> 610         test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
        611         for i in range(self.n_splits):
        612             yield test_folds == i

    C:\Anacondav3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _make_test_folds(self, X, y, groups)
        595         for test_fold_indices, per_cls_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_cls_cvs)):
        596             for cls, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_y, per_cls_splits):
    --> 597                 cls_test_folds = test_folds[y == cls]
        598                 # the test split can be too big because we used
        599                 # KFold(...).split(X[:max(c, n_splits)]) when data is not 100%

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Is there a different way that I should be declaring the array or dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the example in the [User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) shows that `X` is 2-dimensional while `y` is 1-dimensional:

```
>>> X_train.shape, y_train.shape
((90, 4), (90,))
```

Some programmers use capitalized variables for 2-dimensional arrays and lower-case for 1-dimensional arrays.

Therefore use

```
Y = result['label']
```

instead of

```
Y = result[['label']]
```

---

I am assuming that `result` is a pandas DataFrame. When you index a Dataframe with a list of columns such as `['label']`, a sub-DataFrame -- which is 2-dimensional -- is returned. If you index the DataFrame with a single string, a 1-dimensional Series is returned.

---

Finally, note that the IndexError

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

is raised on this line

```
cls_test_folds = test_folds[y == cls]
```

because `y` is 2-dimensional so `y == cls` is a 2-dimensional *boolean* array and `test_folds` is 1-dimensional. The situation is similar to the following:

```
In [72]: test_folds = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.int)
In [73]: y_eq_cls = np.array([(True, ), (False,)])
In [74]: test_folds[y_eq_cls]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I did change  to Y = result['label'] . Will I have to do the same for Variable X as well? Is there a different way I need to index the X array too as I get  a similar "not in index" error for X too